# Function within a function (R programming)

Tags: r

```
linkedin <- c(16, 9, 13, 5, 2, 17, 14)
facebook <- c(17, 7, 5, 16, 8, 13, 14)

interpret <- function(num_views) {
  if (num_views > 15) {
    print("You're popular!")
    return(num_views)
  } else {
    print("Try to be more visible!")
    return(0)
  }
}


interpret_all <- function(views, return_sum = TRUE) {
  count <- 0

  for (v in views) {
    count <- count + interpret(v)
  }

  if (return_sum) {
    return(count)
  } else {
    return(NULL)
  }
}

interpret_all(linkedin)
interpret_all(facebook)
```

I totally understand the interpret function. However, I've difficulty in understanding  if and else statement within the for loop. Kindly break down what's the purpose of if and else statement in the interpret function. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

An `if` statement that includes an `else` clause is of the form

```
if (condition) { code1 } else ( code2 }
```

The condition is evaluated and

- if the condition is TRUE then code1 is run (and code2 is ignored) or
- if the condition is FALSE then code2 is run (and code1 is ignored).

A flow chart that explains it in diagrammatic form can be found here (see the second flow chart on that page) http://www.programiz.com/r-programming/if-else-statement

Comment: I totally understand. I couldn't understand what difference does return=sum default statement in displaying the output of the interpret_all function. Thanks

Comment: `return_sum` is an argument to the `interpret_all` function.  If you specify it as `TRUE` then the count is returned, e.g.  `interpret_all(linkedin, TRUE)`, and if you specify it as `FALSE` then `NULL` is returned, e.g. `interpret_all(linkedin, FALSE)`.  If you don't specify it at all, e.g. `interpret_all(linkedin)` then it is as if you had specified `TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That part was difficult understand.